# jquery :eq() selector don't work with variable (proper syntax) in ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, selector, equation

I am trying to fill 3 divs using this code

```
                        for(var i = 0; i<3; i++){ 
                        $.ajax({
                                        type: "post",
                                        url: "/cake/orders/calendar/", 
                                        data: postData[i],
                                        success: function(response) { $(".ajaxCell:eq("+ i +")").html(response);},

                        });
                        }
```

Seems like everything is allright, variables are set, response recieved... and works with :eq(0) ...or 1 or 2
But I can't get it working with variable.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This should work. Try printing the selector to make sure it's what you want. You can also try `$('.ajaxCell').eq(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're capturing the variable not the value of the variable in each iteration of the loop. When the request returns it uses the value of the variable at the time the request returns, not when the request was made.  Call a function which does the ajax request with the index as an argument so that the value is captured in that function invocation.

```
for(var i = 0; i<3; i++){
   doRequest(i);
}

function doRequest(i) {
    var selector = ".ajaxCell:eq("+ i +")";
    $.ajax({
             type: "post",
             url: "/cake/orders/calendar/", 
             data: postData[i],
             success: function(response) { $(selector).html(response);},
    });
}
```